# How to confirm the last entry of a linked hash list

Tags: cryptography, hash, sha256

We use a linked hash list for data integrity.

Content is hashed (HMAC-SHA256) and stored in a block that itself is hashed and referenced in the next block:

Simplified example:

```
...
{
   id: "block1",
   cId: "A",
   cHash: "hashOfA",
   pId: "block0",
   pHash: "hashOfBlock0",
   t: time
},
{
   id: block2,
   cId: "B",
   cHash: "hashOfB",
   pId: "block1",
   pHash: "hashOfBlock1",
   t: time
},
...
```

This enables us to detect changes in the content. The only problem we have is, that we cannot detect a whole replacement of the latest block that was added to the list. As this block has no following block that confirms it.

How can we confirm that the last block is not altered/replaced?

We thought about a top hash of the complete hash list securely stored somewhere else and is updated every time a new block is created.
But how could we confirm the top hash is not altered?
What would be a secure storage for this hash? Public?
Are there some other solutions?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to reinvent a **Blockchain** . See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain

Comment: it's no reinventing it's a blockchain, but without the decentralized storage and proof of work - just a simple linked hash list - as we use it only for data integrity within our system.

Comment: *'it's a blockchain, but without the ... proof of work' *.  This is exactly why blockchains have a proof of work.  The proof of work solves the problem that you are trying to solve.  Blocks cannot be added or replaced without the proof of work.  That makes it very difficult for an attacker to replace a block with his own - doing so would require a massive amount of computing power.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) (also named "tag" sometimes) of the last entry at a safe place. What safe means here depends on your threat model, but it should at least resit to the following attack:

Be warned that if the attacker can read this MAC at any point in time and has write access to it, it can restore the chain to a previous version by overwriting the MAC. For this the attacker does not need to know the secret authentication key used to compute the MAC.

To prevent a rollback of your chain, you must ensure that the MAC cannot be rolled back without noticing. This might be done for example by using a web service to store it and keep its history.

It was suggested to you to insert this MAC in the first node of the chain. If this MAC were part of the hashed data of the first node, this would introduce an unsolvable cycle of hashes. Thus, the MAC of the last node must be saved outside the structure of the hashed chain.

As a side note, this MAC can be based on a hash function like [HMAC-SHA256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), or it can be a fast (and still secure) MAC like [SipHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SipHash). Other secure algorithms exist, but just ensure that the produced tag is at least 128 bits long and that the secret key is generated by a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) and of at least 128 bits.

Comment: so this is more or less a similiar approach like the top hash of the hashlist ?

Comment: @codeteq Yes. If your threat model allows it, you can store this MAC in the first node, as suggested in the answer of kelalaka.

Comment: To prevent a rollback you must ensure that the MAC cannot be rolled back without noticing. This might be done for example by using a web service to store it and keep its history.

Comment: @A.Hersean could you write a complete answer including the points in my answer, too? This Q doesn't need two answers. Inform me when you done, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @kelalaka I've improved my answer. I'm not sure that it satisfies what you wanted. If not, please ask me exactly which point or detail you want me to improve further.

Comment: The MAC can be stored in a Bitcoin chain, paper, too. There is another method that the MAC value can be used as a public key in the certificate chain.

Comment: @kelalaka I will refrain for suggesting the use of a blockchain, which almost always introduce more issues than it solves. It is indeed possible the use cryptographic signatures instead of MACs, but it is far less efficient.

Comment: Could you provide some links for the issues that I can read?

Comment: There's a lot of literature on it, but it is masked by the huge amount of crappy blog posts or article done by blockchain fanboys. It boils done to the fact that blockchain is very highly inefficient for almost everything (except money speculation), and almost everything that can be done with blockchain can be done more efficiently and more simply without it, just by trying to solve the problem instead of trying to use "blockchain" because it sounds cool. Most real success stories about projects using blockchain do not in fact use blockchain in the backend, it's used just for marketing.

Comment: Even the OP's problem (that does not use blockchain but an authenticated linked list) might be better solved just by proper authentication and access control. Which, in the end, it still needs to do to protect the MAC of the last node of the linked list.